# Permissions denied while editing tags of a video file

Tags: windows, video, permissions

I have a video file on my desktop.
Whenever I try to edit (editing or removing) the tags (title, comments, genre...) of it, I got the following message:

[Access denied](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DYCMN.png) (I edited the same dialog box which was in English because my system isn't)
The system tells me I need permissions from myself (my user account) to edit the file.

So I'm locked out from editing the tags; however, I can do everything else on the file (move, copy, or even delete).

I tried to check the permissions in the Security tab: I have all the rights on the file, and I tried as well to reattribute the file to myself (as well as the parent directory), this does nothing.

Does somebody has a solution for this? It isn't the first time I run into this problem, some time ago I already encountered it upon moving files.

Answer (score 0):

If it is an mkv file, windows doesn't natively support meta data modification. I would recommend mkvmerge in the mkvtoolnix suite for your requirement.

mp4 files should not have any problem in windows. Any other format, check out ffmpeg.